# Can a service get a reference to the activity during onBind?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a service that basically manages a **MediaPlayer** instance for playing **podcasts**. Once an activity binds to the service it can do things like play, pause, stop, etc. I used a service because I want the podcast to continue playing even after the activity is destroyed.

I'd like the service to be able to **send messages back to the activity in case of an error or for normal status updates**.  Is it possible for the service to get a reference to the activity that's trying to bind to it?  Doesn't look like the intent makes this available.

Comment: i dont know for sure but you might search on broadcasting messages from the service, or intents. You have to realise that an activity could be destroyed at any point in time, hence having a reference to it in a service probably wont work. However an activity can respond to messages or intents.

Comment: I hadn't thought if it in those terms, but after some more reading it seems that using notifications is the preferred way of communicating from a component running in the background.  Because as you said, the activity may not be around anymore.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SDK samples API Demos app has an example of a service that messages back to an activity

Comment: Based on your suggestion I found the RemoteService example, which does provide for this functionality.  In my case the service is local so I don't think I need to deal with IPC stuff.  I decided to register my activity with the service as a listener when it binds to handle the communication.